# css level 4 @media queries not working as expected

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, media-queries

I just started learning CSS media queries and as the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#syntax_improvements_in_level_4) says

> In Media Queries Level 4 this can be written as:
>
> ```
> @media (width <= 30em) { ... }
> ```

but when I try the same it gives an error and if I replace <= with a : the error goes away. I need to know how to use the level 4 syntax in media queries. thanks in advance.

```
@media (width <= 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
        color: mediumvioletred;
    }
    nav a {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        color: mediumaquamarine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio Code does not support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/issues/213) the level 4 range syntax yet. Additionally MDN says that only Firefox supports the syntax at the moment. If you need cross-browser support you'll need to stick with the original `max-width` syntax for now:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
        color: mediumvioletred;
    }
    nav a {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        color: mediumaquamarine;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, what you have is correct.